# How do I tell when GroundOverlays in kml have finished loading?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I'm doing this:

```
google.earth.fetchKml(ge, slopehref, function(kmlObject){
  if (kmlObject){
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
    // GroundOverlay's still not rendered
  }
});
```

So I know when the kml file is loaded but then it takes a few seconds to load the GroundOverlays. I want to get a callback when the GroundOverlays have rendered.  I have been looking for google.earth.addEventListener eventids that might fire when network activity has stopped but I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, there is no way to do this in the current Api. The best you could do is to put a feature request in for this functionality to be added:
http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/list

There is a similar request already in there as well if you wanted to 'star' it:
http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=5